# How to exit a do until loop for a (Search Data In Text File and Replace the Data Operation)?

Tags: vb.net

Below is my current code:

```
Private Sub searchdata()

readText = File.ReadAllLines(x)

    Do Until readText(n) = SrchTxBx.Text
        n = n + 1
        'If n > readText.Length Then Exit Do
    Loop

    If readText(n) = SrchTxBx.Text Then
        CmbFound.Items.Add(SrchTxBx.Text)
    Else
        MsgBox("Data not found")
    End If

End Sub
```

My objective is for my search function, to find a specific data stored in a text file. So I used string array to locate my data and rewrite it with a new data. My problem is that, my do until condition is currently set to infinite. I'm really not sure how to exit the do until loop if there is no matching data in the entire text file. Please do guide me.

EDIT 1.0

```
 Private Sub searchdata()
    Dim textFound As Boolean = False
    readText = File.ReadAllLines(x)

    Do Until textFound = True
        If readText(n) = SrchTxBx.Text Then
            textFound = True
        Else
            n = n + 1
        End If

    Loop

    If textFound = True Then
        CmbFound.Items.Add(SrchTxBx.Text)
    Else
        MsgBox("Data not found")
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks to Tim my code has been improved, but now I face new problem as shown in the attached picture:

[image: ERROR Message]

Edit 2.0

latest code:

```
 Private Sub searchdata()
    Dim textFound As Boolean = False
    readText = File.ReadAllLines(x)

    Do Until n > readText.Length - 1 Or textFound = True
        If readText(n) = SrchTxBx.Text Then
            textFound = True
        Else
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Loop
    If textFound = True Then
        CmbFound.Items.Add(SrchTxBx.Text)
    Else
        MsgBox("Data not found")
        n = 0  ' forgotten to reset n value here
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub SubmitBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitBtn.Click
    MessageBox.Show("Do You want to Save the Changes Made to This Document", "Format File_
                     Notification", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If vbYes Then
        readText(n) = RtbReplace.Text
        File.WriteAllLines(x, readText)
        n = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks @Tim, now my search function works. If anyone got a simpler or a better way of executing this method please do share. Thanks

Comment: Use a flag - set it to true if you find the text (And exit the loop).  After the loop is exited if the flag is true you found the text, otherwise it wasn't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example to illustrate my comment:

```
Dim textFound As Boolean = False
Dim n As Integer = 0

readText = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)

Do Until n > readText.Length - 1 OrElse textFound = True 
    If readText(n) = SrchTxBx.Text Then 
        textFound = True
    Else
        n = n + 1
    End If
Loop
```

The flag `textFound` is set to False initially (the default value).  Then the Do Until loop is entered, starting with the first line in the array.

If the line matches the text to search for, the flag is set to True and the loop will be exited.  Otherwise, `n` is incremented by 1 and the next line is checked.

Outside the loop, you can check the value of the flag - if it's True, then `n` will have the index of the line that matched the search string.  If it's false, no match was found.

**EDIT**

Based on your last comment that it appears you can't re-run the `Do Until` loop, when looking at your posted updated code, you use `n` for the line number.  It doesn't appear to be declared in the method, so I'm going to guess it's a class-level variable.  You need to make sure you set it to 0 before you call the method, otherwise subsequent calls will fail because `n` is greater than the number of lines in the file (if you're using the same file).

Example:  30 line file, `n` starts at 0 (default for an `Integer`).  You search and don't find the text.  `n` is now 30.  You start a new search, `n` starts at 30 and the loop is never entered because `n` is greater than the number of lines in the file.

Comment: Thank you, for your guidance. But when i searched data not listed in text file, I get this error :Index was outside the bounds of the array. @Tim

Comment: @GirlsdoCode - Oops, my bad.  You need to check two things - both the text found flag and that you haven't exceeded the number of lines in the array.  I've updated my code to reflect that.

Comment: there is a slight problem, once the do while condition is exited it is not possible to call the loop again, example if at first i searched a data which is not listed in text file,  a message box appears as preset, but when i search again for a data listed in text file, the message box still appears. it seems that i could not call back the do loop @Tim

Comment: @GirlsdoCode - See my edit.  I'm guessing you didn't reset `n` to 0 before calling the method again.

Comment: my bad, I forgot to reset n's value after the message box. Now its working fine.